# Duplicate Count on key column CSV file python 3

Tags: csv, python-3.x, duplicates

I am having the delimited file.(CSV/PIPE delimited file)

**Sample File:**

```
Id,Name,Age
1,ads,23
2,dfg,24
2,hgh,25
3,fgh,26
4,fdfgh,27
4,fh,28
```

I have to get the **duplicate count** on the column **Id** and also separate file (duplicates) should be created. Both the duplicate count and also file with duplicates should be created.

Output should look like

**Console:** it should print like

```
ID : 
2 is repeated 2 times
4 is repeated 2 times
```

**output file** Should look like

```
ID:
2 is repeated 2 times 
4 is repeated 2 times
```

Here is my sample code.

```
import sys
import csv
import datetime
import time
import os from operator
import itemgetter from collections
import Counter

d = ','
read1 = csv.reader(open('D:\ANACONDS\example.csv','r'),delimiter=d)
sort_src = sorted(read1, key=itemgetter(0))
g = len(list(csv.reader(open('D:\ANACONDS\example.csv'))))
print("the number of records are :" ,g)
ids = Counter()
for row in sort_src:
    ids += Counter([row[0]])
    print(len(list(ids)))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Indentation is important in Python - please fix the code formatting in your question. Also, please provide the actual output you're getting from your code for the sample inputs, so it can be compared to the output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to quantify categories, you could use an histogram, you can achieve
histograms by using simple 'dict'. Each category, in your case the 'id', can be used to summarize how often appears in your file. I hope the next code helps you.

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

histogram = dict()

with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_read = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')    
    sort_src = sorted(csv_read, key=itemgetter(0))
    print("The Number of records:", len(sort_src))
    #    
    for row in sort_src:
        if row[0].isdigit(): #Because you don't want to count headers
            if row[0] in histogram:
                histogram[row[0]] += 1
            else:
                histogram[row[0]] = 1       

    #
for item in sorted(histogram.items()):
    print('ID {0} is repeated {1} times'.format(item[0], item[1]))        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Running the code for desired output.
    The Number of records: 7,
    ID 1 is repeated 1 times,
    ID 2 is repeated 2 times,
    ID 3 is repeated 1 times,
    ID 4 is repeated 2 times,

By the way, i see a lot of open's and the path of your file in your code. You can use a context manager which allows to have a cleaner code, and reduce the imports if you ain't going to use them.

Comment: Thanks for that..This is what i was looking for. In above code we are printing for all records(Both duplicate and non duplicate). I want to print only repeated ids ignoring which are distinct. Please guide me regarding this?

Comment: Of course yes, the only you need to do is to modify the last 'for loop' by adding an if as follow 'if(item[1] > 1): print('ID {0} is repeated {1} times'.format(item[0], item[1]))' this is to check whether you have occurrences above to 1. I hope this little modification helps you.

Answer (score 0):

To see only repeated Items only modify the for loop block as follow:

```
for item in sorted(histogram.items()):
    if(item[1] > 1):
        print('ID {0} is repeated {1} times'.format(item[0], item[1]))
```